# how do a batch that counts a file in a directory using a wildcard?

Tags: windows, batch-file, count, directory

For example:
(this should work both in computer local or network, but im giving an example here as local) a code/ directory like this:

where, (anything) means folders that i dont know.. but inside these folders (or not), theres a (mainfolder) as described. I wanna count only if are found files inside that (mainfolder).

..

Guys sorry if i was not clear. Let me try this time:

**D:\A\B** :  this is the server or local path that doesnt change.

**anything** : are subdirectories. Could be anything. Could have one or more subdirectories. It may or not include mainfolder. I dont know how many or names. need to search among these.

**Mainfolder** : is a folder where these kind of files are stored. Mainfolder is needed today. it could be used tomorrow or not. Its name could change in the future. Today is called "mainfolder". this should be a variable. %mainfolder%.
could be: 
images\%file%.png 
PNGS\%file%.png
asteroid\%file%.png

**file** :  is not the same file. its a variable. %file% Its any file with that extension. But if i need to find a word within.. like "*%file%*.extension"

some examples:
D:\A\B\anything\mainfolder\%file% 
*(found file. counts files. 1 or more file)*

D:\A\B\anything\anything\anything\anything\anything\mainfolder\%file% 
*(found file. counts files. 1 or more file)*

D:\A\B\anything\anything\mainfolder\%file% 
*(found file. counts files. 1 or more file)*

D:\A\B\anything\anything\mainfolder\anything\%file% 
*(found file. counts files. 1 or more file)*

D:\A\B\anything\%file%
*(not found, because we are searching only files inside mainfolder)*

thanks again.

---

```
SET myFileCount=0 
%file% = file.txt

D:\A\B\anything\mainfolder\%file% do do set /A myFileCount+=1
```

Comment: Please, in order to anwer the question accordingly, we would need to clarify if besides trying to find some main folder, you are also looking for a file that is always named the same. Also, do you need to look at subdirectories of mainfolder?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

If you want to include subfolders:

```
@echo off
set file=new.txt
set /A count=0
REM D:\A\B\    +    anything    +    \mainfolder\    +  file
for /F %%a in ('dir /A-D /S /B D:\A\B\ ^| findstr /I /R "\\mainfolder\\.*\\%file%$"') do (
  echo %%a
  set /A count+=1
)
for /F %%a in ('dir /A-D /S /B D:\A\B\ ^| findstr /I /R "\\mainfolder\\%file%$"') do (
  echo %%a
  set /A count+=1
)
echo count is %count%
```

If you don't want to include subfolders:

```
@echo off
set /A count=0
set file=new.txt
REM D:\A\B\    +    anything    +    \mainfolder\    +  file
for /F %%a in ('dir /A-D /S /B D:\A\B\ ^| findstr /I /R "\\mainfolder\\%file%$"') do (
  echo %%a
  set /A count+=1
)
echo count is %count%
```

you need to change the for. On the `dir` command use your directory before the 'anything' part. On the findstr, change the name of the mainfolder.

**Example input:**

```
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\new.txt
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\new2.txt
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\X\new.txt
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\X\new2.txt
D:\A\B\D\notmainfolder\new.txt
D:\A\B\D\notmainfolder\new2.txt
D:\A\B\E\mainfolder\new.txt
D:\A\B\E\mainfolder\new2.txt
```

**Example output (with subfolders):**

```
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\X\new.txt
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\new.txt
D:\A\B\E\mainfolder\new.txt
count is 3
```

**Example output (with no subfolders):**

```
D:\A\B\C\mainfolder\new.txt
D:\A\B\E\mainfolder\new.txt
count is 2
```

Comment: what about `D:\A\B\anything\mainfolder\subfolder\file.ext`? (sadly the question doesn't clearly state if they should be included or not; from the way it's written I'd assume they shouldn't - your code does include them)

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer to include both options

Comment: The question is unclear, but what is clear ia that the user wants the count of a specific file, your answer does not provide an answer to that question at all.

Comment: I don't think that's *so* clear that the user wants to count some specific file. He said `I wanna count only if are found **files** inside that` If the file is always the same, it would'nt make any sense, as you cannot repeat same name on same directory. Unless it is at some sudirectory, but you already made a point before that it seems that he doesn't want the subdirectories to be included...

Comment: Asked @rodrigo to clarify. In the meantime, I changed the answer to always look for the same file

Comment: That portion is clear. The user shows an example. `set /A myFileCount+=1` and the heading states count.